# Issues checking out code from Google Code

Tags: 11.10, git, svn, ssl

I've recently upgraded to Ubuntu 11.10 and since then, I haven't been able to checkout code from Google Code.  I can't get it with either svn or git, but they were both working before the upgrade (so I'm assuming it's a problem with 11.10).

SVN:

```
$ svn checkout https://project.googlecode.com/svn/ project --username me@gmail.com
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://project.googlecode.com/svn': SSL handshake failed: Secure connection truncated (https://project.googlecode.com)
```

Git:

```
$ git clone https://me@code.google.com/p/project/ 
Cloning into project...
Password: 
error: gnutls_handshake() failed: A TLS packet with unexpected length was received. while accessing https://me@code.google.com/p/project/info/refs

fatal: HTTP request failed
```

Any ideas?

```
git version 1.7.5.4
svn, version 1.6.12 (r955767)
openssl 1.0.0e-2ubuntu4
libneon27-gnutls 0.29.6-1
```

Edit:

Just confirmed with my 11.04 netbook that I can checkout Google Code via https with subversion.

I compiled subversion-1.7.0 from source using the neon 0.29.6 and openssl with no luck.  It now gives `svn: E175002`.

Edit 2:

Just to be clear, I only seem to have this problem with Google Code.  I can check out code from all of the other repositories that I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also had this problem when moving to 11.10 (although with an Assembla SVN repo, not Google code). This solution from [Jan Kester's blog](http://jankesterblog.blogspot.com/2011/03/ssl-handshake-failed-secure-connection.html) worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libneon27
cd /usr/lib/
sudo rm libneon-gnutls.so.27
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27 libneon-gnutls.so.27
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's weird, but I had run across this and tried it earlier.  I attempted it again just for grins and apparently it works now.  I guess I made a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

it's working fine here with the same svn version as yourself. Can you try backing up/removing/renaming your `~/.ssh` and `~/.subversion` folders and seeing if that helps matters.

I see that the above solved the same issue for [other users](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1511387) on earlier Ubuntu versions.

Comment: Yea, I've already tried that several times.  Forgot to mention it >.< (Tried it again just now to be sure though)

Answer (score 0):

Just use http:// protocol instead https:// if you can. Worked for me.

Comment: This worked perfectly for my needs this time, but I imagine some repositories are only available over an SSL connection.